# Working with more than 1 person on a website?

Tags: project-management

This is semi-programming related. I'm working with more than 1 person on a website. And its really hard not to mess up each others work by downloading/uploading the wrong file to FTP. So we started using dropbox, which auto-syncs the files. It's not perfect...

How do you work with multiple people? Is there something like Google Docs, that has live editing? Or any other neat solutions?

Comment: Google Docs DOES have live editing and I believe also has a history for reverting to previous version.  However, SVN and Git are better choices as you increase your number of programmers.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant with Google Docs. I can't connect it with FTP and work with folders tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at a source control system. They allow multiple people to make changes to the same project and also allow you to see/undo changes that have been made. SVN or GIT are the two most popular right now.

Tortoise SVN - http://tortoisesvn.net/
Git - http://git-scm.com/

Comment: Thanks! Github looks good, I'll check it out. I assume there are no free alternatives?

Comment: "Free for open source" aha! Smart, thanks! I know enough, thanks for answering.

Comment: @user1333327: Using [Git](http://git-scm.com), which is free and open source and can be used for any kind of project, does not require using http://github.com, which is a commercial service that offers a "free" usage tier for open source projects.

Comment: Yeah sorry to mislead on that. Git can be used without it. Thanks for updating the link.